# kubectl exec -it <POD> getting sh: can't open 'export': No such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, sh, kubectl

i try to execute this command :

```
alias kubectl_winpty='winpty kubectl'   ( using winpty due to [bug][1] 
kubectl_winpty exec -it vault-0 -n vault-xxx -- sh export VAULT_CACERT=/vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.ca
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
sh: can't open 'export': No such file or directory
command terminated with exit code 2
```

the pod do exist and running

```
$ kubectl get pods vault-0 -n vault-xxx
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
vault-0   0/1     Running   0          17m
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess `sh export` makes shell to assume export as a filename (some script that shell will run). Hence the error `can't open 'export': No such file or directory`.

Try to make use of `-c` option.

```
kubectl_winpty exec -it vault-0 -n vault-xxx -- sh -c "export VAULT_CACERT=/vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.ca"
```

Also it's better to [set env variable when you create this pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/).

Also make sure [your pod is healthy and in ready state](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/), which is not the case as per `kubectl get` output.